# How to pass value from html input to javascript correctly?

Tags: javascript

How can I pass value from html input to javascript I have value_1 = 0 but when I change it in input form I want code inside if to happen.

```
<body>
<input type="number" name="a" id="commands"><br>
<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>

<script>
const value_1 = 0;
const value_1 = document.getElementById("commands").value;

if(value_1 != 0)
{
 //code
}
</script>    
</body>
```

Comment: So you need to add an event listener. You just check it when the page loads.

Comment: You will need to associate an event listener with the input; see documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Be aware, in your code you are trying to reassign a constant value, this should throw an error. In your case you could skip the line `const value_1 = 0;` entirely because one line later you reassign the value of `value_1`

Answer (score 1):

add a listener for the 'keyup' event, as follows:

```
document.getElementById("commands").addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
   let value = document.getElementById("commands").value;
   if (value !== 0) {
      // code
   }
});
```

Or like this:

```
document.getElementById("commands").onkeyup = function(e) {
   let value = document.getElementById("commands").value;
   if (value !== 0) {
      // code
   }
}
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#commands').on('keyup', (e) => {
   let value = $('#commands').val();
   if (value !== 0) {
      // code
   }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using `!==` instead of `!=`

Comment: You're right, it's better. I just copied the original snippet of the interviewer's code. @thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use addEventListener with change event type or use the onchange property.

Example:

```js
    <script>
    const value_1 = document.getElementById("commands");

    value_1.onchange = function(){
        if(value_1.value != 0)
        {
            console.log("Not 0");//code
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood,

To track input value changes you could do so by:

1. Initialize the variable:

```
var inputValue = "";
```

2. Listen for input changes (There are multiple ways to do it, I will use the one which listen whenever user clicks button on the input):

```
document.getElementById("commands").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  inputValue = document.getElementById("commands").value;
  
  // Here you can do anything, incase you need to have a callback whenever the value changes.
  // Example:
  if(inputValue != 0) {
    // code.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass value from html to JavaScript correctly using following code:**

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="return getValue('commands')">
  <input type="number" name="a" id="commands">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function getValue(id) {
        let value_1 = 0;
        value_1 = document.getElementById(id).value;
        alert(value_1);
        
        if(value_1 != 0)
        {
         //code
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```